# Realm results sort by callback

Tags: swift, sorting, realm

I have a "importData" function that grabs a bunch of JSON from an API and stuffs it into a realm database. Part of that json looks like:

```
files: [
  300,
  19,
  102
]
```

The numbers relate to id's in order parts of the JSON that i have already processed/imported prior to getting to these, and is basically just a list of files that belong to the group.

This is modelled like so in my Realm Object:

```
class SomeGroup : Object {
    let files = List<File>()
}
```

I need to preserve the sorting order of these id's so that when i link up the files relationship, the files are in the correct order.

In order to grab the file models i need to link up i run a query as follows:

```
let thefiles = realm.objects(File.self).filter("id IN %@", fileIds)
```

the problem is this returns them in a different order and the `.sorted` method can only sort by the model attributes (from what i can tell from the docs).

I considered looping through the results and turning them from a `Result<File>` type to a basic `Array<File>` or `List<File>` type so i can sort them myself, however that would lose the realm pointer information and therefore i would expect realm to not be able to create the link.

The only other thing is to query each file and append it separately to the group files relationship, however the query counts are going to skyrocket if i do that.

Could someone advise me the best way to order the `Result<File>` type by a custom function/callback so that it matches my id array from the json?

Comment: If the order in which the files are added to the collection is relevant to your model and workflow then you should add an "order" key to the model (the `File` object). You set it when you iterate the JSON input and create `File` objects and you use it later in the query to get the correct order.

Comment: @bogdanf it's a many-to-many relationship. To set an order key i'd have to place the order on the relationship (akin to an extra column on a pivot table in mysql).

Comment: Yes, correct, why not create a "relationship" object with a link to the group and file in it as well as the order of the file ?

Comment: @bogdanf Sure, i could create a pivot object, but i'm trying to work out if there's a more elegant solution, given realm list's keep their order, the only thing causing a problem is ordering that list for insertion, everything else is already supported. Finding a solution that just works is relatively simple, the reason i posted the question was to ascertain if there was a way of doing this without re-modelling my data

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for maintaining the ordering of a set of objects in Realm is to simply store them in a `List` object. If you can adjust your logic to access the `files` property in `SomeGroup`, that seems like the best approach.

Beside that, as hacky as it might seem, you can potentially consider creating a whole new Realm `Object` model whose role is to simply manage the ordered list of files.

```
class FileList : Object {
    let files = List<File>()
}
```

Comment: What you suggested is exactly what i started with and was making use of the fact Lists maintain their sortorder. The problem is the List is created from a realm result query which is in the wrong order. Because the relation is many-to-many i cannot store the order as an integer on the file object (a file is in different positions depending on the group it's being displayed in). I wanted to be able to sort the list using a custom sort function, however sorting realm result objects doesn't allow this. I ended up going with an intermediate pivot object in the end, as i couldn't work it out